# Ler e guardar informação (C++)

Tags: c++

Boa tarde.

Eu estou desenvolvendo um projeto cujo objetivo é gerir os **condutores** de uma companhia de mobilidade.

Aqui está o que já fiz... guardar registos de um novo condutor no ficheiro "condutor.txt".

```
    #include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream archivo("condutor.txt"); //arquivo de texto onde se armazena a informacao

    int idunico; //numero identificador unico
    string nome; //nome do condutor
    int horas_dia; //numero de horas consecutivas que pode conduzir por dia (turno)
    int horas_semana; //numero maximo de horas que pode conduzir por semana
    int horas_descanso; //numero minimo de horas de descanso obrigatorio entre turnos
    int op1; //introduzir novo registo
    int op2; //sair

    do {
        cout << "1) Novo resgisto de condutor" << endl;
        cout << "2)Sair" << endl;
        cin >> op1;
        cin.ignore();

        if (op1 == 1)
        {
            if (!archivo.is_open())
            {
                archivo.open("condutor.txt", ios::out);
            }

            cout << "Numero identificador unico: ";
            getline(cin, idunico);
            cout << "Nome do condutor: ";
            getline(cin, nome);
            cout << "Numero de horas consecutivas que pode conduzir por dia (turno): ";
            getline(cin, horas_dia);
            cout << "Numero maximo de horas que pode conduzir por semana: ";
            getline(cin, horas_semana);
            cout << "Numero minimo de horas de descanso obrigatorio entre turnos: ";
            getline(cin, horas_descanso);

            cout << "1) Guardar registo de condutor.";
            cout << "2) Regressar";
            cin >> op2;

            if (op2 == 1)
            {
                archivo << idunico << " ; " << nome << " ; " << horas_dia << " ; " << horas_semana << " ; " << horas_descanso << endl;
                system("cls");

                cout << "Registo de condutor guardado com sucesso!\n";
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
            }
            archivo.close();
        }

    }while (op1 != 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Error list:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Output:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sou iniciante em C++ e não estou entender qual o erro. Alguém me esclareça, pf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro, você esqueceu do header do tipo string:

```
 #include <string>
```

Segundo, o problema é que "getline" apenas aceitas strings. Você primeiro precisar converter os valores numéricos. Se vc tá usando um compilador compatível com C++11/14, pode converter com std::to_string:

```
cout << "Numero identificador unico: ";
getline(cin, to_string(idunico));
```

Obs: não entendi pq você tá lendo os valores inteiros com getline. Não seria melhor usar o std::cin diretamente ?

```
int valor;
cin >> valor;
```

Ou então declarar todas as variáveis como string logo de uma vez ?

Comment: Muito obrigado. Funcionou.